# Conditions with And Or statements

Tags: sql, cakephp

**I got this figured out. Here is the solution:**

```
'conditions'=>array(
     'OR' => array(
          array('EavAttribute.attribute_code'=>'lastname'),                            
          array('EavAttribute.attribute_code'=>'firstname')
      ),
     'AND' => array(
          array('UserEntityVarchar.entity_id'=>$id)
     )
)
```

I am trying to convert this query into a cakephp query and I am having a bit of trouble with the conditions. No matter how I format the conditions, I always end up with the second query below.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

This is the query I am trying to replicate:

```
SELECT
    `UserEntityVarchar`.`value_id`,
    `UserEntityVarchar`.`attribute_id`,
    `UserEntityVarchar`.`entity_id`,
    `UserEntityVarchar`.`value`,
    `EavAttribute`.`attribute_code`
FROM
    `user_entity_varchars` AS `UserEntityVarchar`
LEFT JOIN `eav_attributes` AS `EavAttribute` ON(
    `UserEntityVarchar`.`attribute_id` = `EavAttribute`.`attribute_id`)
WHERE
     (UserEntityVarchar.entity_id = 1 AND
     EavAttribute.attribute_code = 'firstname') OR
     (UserEntityVarchar.entity_id = 1 AND
     EavAttribute.attribute_code = 'lastname')
```

This is the query I keep getting no matter how I format my condition:

```
SELECT
    `UserEntityVarchar`.`value_id`,
    `UserEntityVarchar`.`attribute_id`,
    `UserEntityVarchar`.`entity_id`,
    `UserEntityVarchar`.`value`,
    `EavAttribute`.`attribute_code`
FROM
    `user_entity_varchars` AS `UserEntityVarchar`
LEFT JOIN `eav_attributes` AS `EavAttribute` ON(
    `UserEntityVarchar`.`attribute_id` = `EavAttribute`.`attribute_id`)
WHERE 
    ((`UserEntityVarchar`.`entity_id` = 1)
AND
    (`EavAttribute`.`attribute_code` = 'firstname'))
AND
    ((`UserEntityVarchar`.`entity_id` = 1)
AND
    (`EavAttribute`.`attribute_code` = 'lastname'))
```

This is the condition that I am using:

```
'conditions'=>array(
    array(
     array('UserEntityVarchar.entity_id'=>$id),
     array('AND ' => array('EavAttribute.attribute_code'=>'firstname'))

    ),
    array('OR' =>
         array('UserEntityVarchar.entity_id'=>$id),
         array('AND ' => array('EavAttribute.attribute_code'=>'firstname'))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
$this->Model->find('all', array('conditions' => array('OR' => array(

              array('UserEntityVarchar.entity_id' => 1, 
              'EavAttribute.attribute_code' => 'firstname'),

              array('UserEntityVarchar.entity_id' => 1, 
              'EavAttribute.attribute_code' => 'lastname')))));
```

Comment: You edited your question to post your solution when I was writting mine. Just a remark about yours. Even if it is logically correct in your case (with twice the $id variable as value), it does not produce the exact SQL query you wanted to replicate. If for any reason you have to produce such a query with 2 different values, you can go with my solution.

Comment: While mine solution does not give the exact query I was looking for, it gives a more optimized query. Your solution works as I originally intended.

Comment: Right, in your specific case your final solution is better.